# grep for RegEx recursiv through directories

Tags: php, regex, recursion, grep

In my PHP-file I want to use grep to search recursive throught a directorystructur.
The searchdirectory and the hostname are given by variables. ($path and $_POST['host_select'])
I tried this:

```
<?PHP
function read_hostfile()
{
$path = '/omd/sites/test/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects';
$string= $_POST['host_select'];
$shellcommand = "grep -E -r -i --include=*cfg 'host_name*switch' $path";
$result = exec($shellcommand);
$hostfile = file($result);
.
.
?>
```

I tried to edit my grep-command as follows:

```
$shellCommand = "grep -E -d=read -r --include='cfg host_name*$string' $path";
```

I got an error for file():

```
execgrep: unknown directories method
file()PHP Warning:  file(): Filename cannot be empty in /home/thomas/configpage_icinga_test/test.php on line 14
```

Comment: go into the directory in which you want to search for then run `grep -E -r 'host_name[\s]*switch*' *` command. `*` after `h` means zero or more times of `h`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `*` before and after `pattern`.

Try this:

```
$shellcommand = "grep -E -r -i --include='cfg host_name.*switch' $path";
```

Comment: I got: grgrep -E -r 'host_name*switch' /omd/sites/test/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects/ -bash: grgrep: command not found| I tryed grep -E -r 'host_name*switch' /omd/sites/test/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects/ although with no result

Comment: grgrep was a misspelling. I edit my primary question to make my problem more clearly.

Comment: The command shell_exec() doesn´t work. I have got the following code:|<?php $path = '/omd/sites/test/etc/icinga/conf.d/objects'; $string= 'switch'; $shellCommand = "grep -E -r -i --include='cfg host_name.*$string' $path"; $result = shell_exec($shellCommand); $hostfile = file($result);... ?>  | The command "shell_exec()" can´t be finished. I tried a echo""; after it but it doesn´t see it.

Comment: I have already tried `exec` and `shell_exec` with the same result.